# Relation of field creation operators to path integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, path-integral

Applying two field creation operators to a vacuum I get:

$$\hat{\psi}^\dagger(x)\hat{\psi}^\dagger(y)|0\rangle = (\hat{\phi}(x)\hat{\phi}(y) - s^{-1}(x-y)) |0\rangle$$

where the quantum field creation operators are defined by (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization#Creation_and_annihilation_operators)

$$\hat{\psi}^\dagger(x) = \int a^\dagger(k)e^{i x.k} dk^3 $$

and $s(x-y) = \int e^{i k.(x-y)} \sqrt{k^2+m^2} dk^3$

But the field operators are **a sum of** creation and annihilation operators:

$$\hat{\phi}(x) = \int ( a^\dagger(k)e^{i x.k} + a(k)e^{-i x.k} ) dk^3$$

$$\hat{\pi}(x) = \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(x)} = \int \sqrt{k^2+m^2}( a^\dagger(k)e^{i x.k} - a(k)e^{-i x.k} ) dk^3$$

and so on. Where $\langle\phi|\hat{\phi}(x)|0\rangle = \phi(x)\langle\phi|0\rangle$. Presumably $\hat{\phi}(x)=\psi(x)+\psi^\dagger(x)$ ?? and

$$ \psi^\dagger(x) = \phi(x) + \int s^{-1}(x-y)\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(y) } dy^3$$

But in the path integral for an input state starting with two particles it is just $\phi(x)\phi(y)$ and not $\phi(x)\phi(y) -s(x-y)$. e.g.

$$\int \phi(x,t)\phi(y,t) \phi(z,t')\phi(w,t') e^{S[\phi]} D\phi$$

Or in other words we calculate $\langle 0|\hat{\phi}(x)\hat{\phi}(y)..|0\rangle$ not $\langle 0|\hat{\psi}(x)\hat{\psi}(y)..|0\rangle$.

Why is this? What happened to the missing $s(x-y)$. Why do we use field operators $\phi$ and not field creation operators $\psi$? **Question: Is it equivalent and if so how can this be proven?**

Am I doing something wrong here? Why this is bothering me is that a complete set of orthogonal states would be given by the field creation operators $\hat{\psi}(x)\hat{\psi}(y)..|0\rangle$ but not I presume the field operators $\phi$.

To put it another way. If $\phi$ represents a photon of light and we are calculating the scattering of two photons. Should we use:

$$\langle 0|\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(z)\phi(w)|0\rangle$$

or

$$\langle 0|(\phi(x)\phi(y)-s(x-y))(\phi(z)\phi(w)-s(w-z))|0\rangle$$

or, for example, are the effects of s so small not to matter when the photons are far away from the scattering point? But which one is "theoretically" correct? I know in scattering experiments where x and y are presumed to start infinitely far apart this doesn't matter but is it correct?

Comment: Please use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>` in your TeX.